# multinode processing in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to run R code on an HPC, but not sure how to take advantage of multiple nodes. The specific HPC I am using has 100 nodes and 36 cores per node.

Here is an example of the code.

```
n = 3600 ### This would be my ideal. Set to 3 on my laptop
cl = makeCluster(n, "SOCK")
foreach(i in 1:length(files), packages=c("raster","dismo")) %dopar%
    Myfunction(files=files[i],template=comm.path, out = outdir)
```

This code works on my laptop and on the login of the HPC, but it is only using 1 node. I just want to make sure I am taking advantage of all the cores that I can.

How specifically do I take advantage of multiple nodes, or is it done "behind the scenes"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are serious with HPC clusters, use MPI cluster, not SOCK.  MPI is the standard for non-shared memory computing, and most clusters are optimized for MPI.

In case of HPC you also need a job-script to start R.  There are several ways to start it, you may use `mpirun`, or invoke the workers directly from R.  Scheduler will set up the MPI environment and R will figure out which nodes to use.  Start small, with say 4 workers, and increase the number until you have reached the optimal level.  Most tasks cannot efficiently use 3600 cpus.

Finally, if you are using tens of CPU-s over MPI, I strongly recommend to use Rhpc instead of Rmpi package. it uses more efficient MPI communication and gives you quite a noticeable speed boost.

On a TORQUE-controlled system I am using something along the lines:

```
Rhpc_initialize()
nodefile <- Sys.getenv("PBS_NODEFILE")
nodes <- readLines(nodefile)
commSize <- length(nodes)
cl <- Rhpc_getHandle(commSize)

Rhpc_Export(cl, c("data"))
...
result <- Rhpc_lapply(cl, 1:1000, runMySimulation)
...
Rhpc_finalize()
```

The TORQUE-specific part is the nodefile part, in this way I know how many workers to create.  In the jobscript I start R just as `Rscript >>output.txt myScript.R`.

As a side note: are you sure `myfun(files, ...)` is correct?  Perhaps you mean `myfun(files[i], ...)`?

Let us know how it goes, I am happy to help :-)